# Strange issue with console.log

Tags: javascript, console.log

```
const myFather = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 78,
  getDetails: function () {
    return 'The name of my father is ' + this.name + ' and he is ' + this.age + ' old.'
  }
}
```

If I run the following line of code, I get true as expected:

```
console.log(myFather.__proto__ === Object.prototype)
```

If I run this, I get the text as expected:

```
console.log('myFather.__proto__ === Object.prototype:')
```

But if I run this, I get only false. Not even the text shows:

```
console.log('myFather.__proto__ === Object.prototype:' + myFather.__proto__ === Object.prototype)
```

I don't understand why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a case of operator precedence? Does it work if you wrap the second part in brackets, like

```js
console.log('myFather.__proto__ === Object.prototype:' + (myFather.__proto__ === Object.prototype))
```

Operator precedence, as documented at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) or other JS core documentation, defines the order in which operators are evaluated. This list is not that interesting in most cases, as simple assignments within one statement might not use multiple different operators. But in your case, there's a `+` operator and the `===` operator. The addition operator has a **higher** precedence than the equality operator, which means: it is evaluated first. So, these are the internal steps for your log call, line by line:

```js
console.log('myFather.__proto__ === Object.prototype:' + myFather.__proto__ === Object.prototype)

console.log('myFather.__proto__ === Object.prototype:[object Object]' === Object.prototype)

console.log(false)
```

Answer (score 4):

You are actually doing this :

```
console.log( ('myFather.__proto__ === Object.prototype:' + myFather.__proto__) === Object.prototype);
```

So the result of this equality is `false`